# Ion Refresher color Icon does not change ionic 5 (stencil)

Tags: ionic-framework, spinner, darkmode

How can I customize the the styles of ionic refresher spinner icon in ionic 5?
I am working on an app with lightmode and darkmode. In lightmode the spinner is displayed in a dark grey on white background. So far so good. But if I switch to darkmode, it is displayed white on white. I tried to change the color f.e. with

```
<ion-refresher slot="fixed">
      <ion-refresher-content color="primary" refreshing-spinner="crescent">
</ion-refresher-content>
```

or SCSS

```
    ion-refresher {
  ion-refresher-content {
      --color: red;
    }
  }

    ion-refresher {
  ion-refresher-content {
      color: red;
    }
  }
```

and setting the variable to

```
$refresher-icon-color: red;
```

I would really appreciate some help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to some CSS to get this done. i have added a CSS code below you can add this in your global.css file and you can remove the color option from `ion-refresher-content color="primary"`

```
//add this css code in your global.scss file which in your src folder
ion-refresher.refresher-native ion-spinner{
    color: red!important;      
}
```